# How to see the environment variable set by the net-SNMP library?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, net-snmp, mib

I am using the `net-SNMP` library for developing a parser for the `MIBs`.
I want to see the environment variable used bye the library.

I have tried the `env` command but it doesn't  showing any variable as follows

MIBDIRS,
MIBS
etc.

Kindly give some idea.

Answer (score 2):

MIBDIRS and MIBS environment variables are used to change default values used by net-SNMP for dirctory that contains MIBs and a list of MIBs to load respectively

default are (according to snmpcmd man [page](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/docs/man/snmpcmd.html)):

```
MIBS = SNMPv2-TC:SNMPv2-MIB:IF-MIB:IP-MIB:TCP-MIB:UDP-MIB:SNMP-VACM-MIB
MIBDIRS = /usr/local/share/snmp/mibs
```

so until you define these environment variables yourself (and override the defaults this way) you won't see them in `env` output